# Statement evaluation on if statement java

Tags: java

If the below "if" stmt evalutes to TRUE then the value of Output = 20 or else 10..

Can someone explain how the increment operator works here.?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int Output = 10;
        boolean b1 = true;
        if ((b1 == true ) && ((Output += 10) == 20)){
            System.out.println("We are Equal = " + Output);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not Equal = " + Output);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not so much the `+=` operator that is working differently; it's the `&&` operator.

The `&&` operator short circuits.  If `b1` is false, there's no way that `b1 && (anything else)` can be true, so it stops evaluating.  As such, `Output += 10` is not evaluated if `b1` is not true, so `Output` will be 10.

If `b1` is true, then it must continue to see if the remainder of the condition is true.  In doing so, it must evaluate `Output += 10`, thereby increasing the value of `Output` by 10, making the value of `Output` 20.

Comment: +1 just want to add that if the `&&` is changed to `&`(bit wise and) then `Output+=10` will always be evaluated since that operation doesn't short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The integer value `10` is added to the current value of `Output`. After this, the value of output is compared using the `==` operator, which only operates on booleans.

In this particular piece of code, since `b1` is true and and Output is 20 after its value is increased by 10, the condition of the `if` block is true, therefore the `else` will be discarded and whatever code is inside the `if` block will be executed.

Answer (score -1):

1)    +=
means a "Pre-increment". So, with `Output=10` the if block would proceed as below

```
if ((b1 == true ) && ((Output = Output + 10) == 20)){
```

here, value of Output will be compared with 20 once incrementation is done..So, during the first time
execution of the if block.. it would proceed as below..

```
if ((b1 == true ) && ((20) == 20)){
```

2)`=+`
means a "post-increment". So, value of Output will be compared with 20 before incrementation..So, during the first time execution of the if block.. it would proceed as below..

```
if ((b1 == true ) && ((10) == 20)){
```

hope this explaination helps :-)

Comment: There is no `=+` operator. The statement `x =+ 10` would assign value `+10` to x.

Comment: Plus, `+=` is a compound assignment operator (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2). Do not confuse this with the preincrement operator (`++x`).